# multiple replace of a letter

Tags: javascript

I have a string variable `var str = 'this is eeeeeeee';`. I want to replace each letter e in this string. When I do `str.replace('e', 'E');` it does it only to the first e

Comment: why you tagged jquery? not need for this case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use regular expressions to indicate you want to replace more than one instance. In this case you would use the `g` flag.

```
'this is eeeeeeeee'.replace(/e/g, 'E')
```

More info can be found at [replace - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
mystr = mystr.replace(/e/g,"E");
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the [global match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) `g` with a regular expression

```
str.replace(/e/g, 'E');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`str.replace('e', 'E', 'g');`