# Javascript string replace unwanted output

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace

I want to replace a part of a string using Replace method but didn't work well:

```
var string = '<a title="%str%" href="#">%str%</a>',
    sub = "Strong";

    console.log(string.replace(/%str%/,sub));

    //result

    <a title="Strong" href="#">%str%</a>
```

It seems that only the first occurrence of %str% have been replaced, the next occurrences where ignored/skipped. Am I missing something here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [multiple replace of a letter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7466341/multiple-replace-of-a-letter)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the "global" regex flag to find multiple ocurrences:

```
/%str%/g
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this, it will do "global" replace.

```
console.log(string.replace(/%str%/g,sub));
```